# How to using the Aptana Studio 3 move file to trash when delete or clean file?

Tags: aptana, delete-file

Is it possible for Aptana to offer a "Move file to trash" option instead of deleting the file directly? I've often accidentally deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if that feature won't/can't be implemented in Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=70810

However, they do mention using local history for the same thing:

"If you have deleted a file in the Navigator, simply right click on the parent folder and select 'Restore from Local History'."